# C++ typecasting with bitwise assignement operation

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I haven't found a way to typecast where bitwise assignment operation (e.g. x |= y &z;) is involved.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum type1{
    AA = 0,
    BB = 1
} type1_e;

int main()
{

  type1_e x,y;

  y = type1_e(y | x); //working

  y |= (type1_e)(y|x); //ERROR: as.cc:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘type1_e’

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can write an overload for bitwise OR (`|`) that works for your enum.
- You will have to use `static_cast` as well for proper conversion.

---

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef enum type1{
    AA = 0,
    BB = 1
} type1_e;

type1_e operator |=(type1_e& x, type1_e y)
{
    return x=static_cast<type1_e>(static_cast<int>(x) | static_cast<int>(y));
}


int main()
{
  type1_e x = AA, y = BB;
  y = type1_e(y | x); //working
  std::cout << y << '\n';

  x = AA, y = AA;
  y |= static_cast<type1_e>(y|x); //also works
  std::cout << y << '\n'; 

}
```

See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a544d95a791114d2).

Comment: Might wanna consider making that operator `constexpr`.

Answer (score 5):

`operator |` yields an `int` result

```
type1_e(y | x)
```

`y | x` is an `int`.  You're explicitly casting that `int` to `type1_e`.

---

```
y |= (type1_e)(y|x);
```

is equivalent to

```
y = y | type1_e(y | x);
```

You are using `operator |` which yields an `int` result, then trying to assign that to `y` which is `type1_e`.  You can't do that without casting.

---

To overcome that, you could do this:

```
y = type1_e(y | type1_e(y | x));
```

which is the same as:

```
y = type1_e(y | y | x);
```

which is the same as:

```
y = type1_e(y | x);
```

or:

```
  y = static_cast<type1_e>(y | x);
```